# What is this button/switch by Garage door connected garage opener

Tags: wiring, garage, garage-door-opener, garage-door

[image: Switch Beside Garage Door]

Moved into this house last year , Trying to figure out what this button does ? the white wire goes to garage opener. .  Tried pressing it while the garage door is opening/closing ,nothing happens.

Comment: What happens if you press it when the door's not moving??

Comment: Did you try it while the door was closed or open. My button cycles the door. opens it if it is closed, closes it if it is open. It  does nothing if the door is in motion.

Comment: Can you add a photograph of how the wires attach to the opener?

Comment: It Does nothing when the buttton is pressed when door is not moving. just found out it is not connected to anything . i will climb and see to which port this wire should connect to ?.

Comment: @mikes, Is it used to force close/open garage door incase  safety sensor is not working .?

Comment: Normally the switch is to open or close the door by pressing the button.

Comment: As @ Ed Beal has stated it is used to open or close the door without using the remote opener.

Comment: Might be a switch installed to just turn on the light separate from the opener. I did that once, because it was the only light in the garage.